# What is the problem with this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, problem-solving, solution-verification

I am stuck a differential equation problem $x^2D^2y-2x(x+2)Dy+6(x+1)y=x^4e^x$,the question is knowing that for some $n$ positive integer ,$x^n$ is a solution of the reduced differential equation,reduce the differential equation to first order ODE.Now we can find out that $x^3$ is the solution mentioned here.So,we have to take the general solution as $y=vx^3$,then by substituting in the given differential equation,we should come up with a form $D^2v+P_1Dv=R_1$,there should be no term with $v$.But when I am substituting in the equation,I am getting $x^2D^2v+(2x-2x^2)Dv-6v=xe^x$,as per my assumption the $-6v$ term should not be there but I have checked my calculation,there is no mistake.So,what has gone wrong?
Can someone tell me why I am getting stuck and where I have made mistake?

Comment: @LostInSpace $x^3$ satisfies the Reduced equation,check it please.

Comment: @LostInSpace What is the relation with cauchy euler here,it is a method of reduction of order.

Comment: Yes sorry I checked it

Comment: I got no term in v ...

Comment: @LostInSpace Can you describe the complete calculation in the answer,please?

Comment: It's a lot of terms that cancel... I will add some steps ok.

Comment: @LostInSpace Write it in an answer Ok,thanks.

Comment: I added some lines I hope it's clear

Comment: @LostInSpace where?

Comment: in mt answer I added some lines

Comment: @LostInSpace ok..

Comment: @LostInSpace Can you help me find an answer to a query regarding https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575945/how-to-simply-represent-topological-spaces-satisfying-separation-axioms

Comment: @LostInSpace I beg pardon because I am asking it even when it is not relevant to this topic.

Comment: Well members will answer it..Don't worry

Comment: @LostInSpace memb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2y''-2x(x+2)y'+6(x+1)y=x^4e^x$$

I got this
$$
\begin {cases}
y=vx^3 \\
y'=v'x^3+3x^2v \\
y''=v''x^3+6x^2v'+6xv
\end{cases}
$$
So that we have:
$$x^2y''=v''x^5+6x^4v'+\color{red}{6x^3v}$$
$$6(x+1)y=\color{blue}{6vx^4}+\color{red}{6x^3v}$$
$$-2x(x+2)y'=-2x^5v'\color{blue}{-6x^4v}-4x^4v'\color{red}{-12x^3v}$$
Now sum the terms ( the terms in v in red and blue cancel as you can see):
$$v''x^5+2x^4v'-2x^5v'=x^4e^x$$
$$x^2v''+2v'x(1-x)=xe^x$$
$$(x^2v')'-2v'x^2=xe^x$$
Integrating factor is $\mu= e^{-2x}$
$$(x^2v'e^{-2x})'=xe^{-x}$$
Integrate:
$$x^2v'e^{-2x}=-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+C$$
$$v'=\dfrac 1{x^2} \left (-xe^{x}-e^{x}+Ce^{2x} \right )$$
Integrate again. You get a solution with the exponetial integral.